# What is the probability that 3 random chords in a circle do not intersect?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, circles, intersection-theory

I understand that for 2 random chords, the probability of no intersections is 1/3 thanks to [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/07/11/probability-two-chords-intersect.html#:%7E:text=Consequently%2C%20the%20probability%20that%20two,of%20the%20three%20possible%20arrangements.).

What happens when I have 3 random chords? Is there an intuitive explanation for calculating the number of intersections given *n* random chords?

I found [a post](https://mathschallenge.net/full/random_chords) that proposes the following formula for *r* chords, but this does not hold for 2 chords. Any ideas?

$$P(NoIntersection) = \frac{2^r}{(r+1)!}$$

*Note: By random chord, I mean by randomly picking 2 points that lie on the circle.*

Comment: You should be careful in defining exactly what it is you mean by "random chord" (see Bertrand's Paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). The posts you link do define it, but I'd like to just make sure you are working with the same definition as them.

Comment: You mean $(r+1)!$?

Comment: Quote: "Is there an intuitive explanation for calculating the number of intersections given $n$ random chords?" The number of intersections has various possible values, each with some probability; I'm not sure what you mean by calculate this number. (It's like saying, toss $10$ coins, then "calculate" the number of heads.) Anyway,  is this question different from the question in the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first linked blog post shows that the probability that two random chords *do intersect* is $\tfrac 13$, which means the probability they *don't intersect* is $\tfrac 23$. This lines up with the formula provided in the second link.